# No output when using multiple dependency injection containers with NLog

Tags: c#, events, logging, nlog

I have set NLog through dependency injection, one place, where I injecting the logger is my main Class `Application`, in this class I have created instance of my Socket Server, where I have events on Accept connection or on error and so on... These events are set in the `Application`.

For example the `OnAccept` event is of course handled by another thread, where is the listening for connection running. When this event is invoked, everything go as it should, but the logger does not write anything in the log. If I use instead of logger `Console.WriteLine()`, it writes everything, so this event is invoked right (checked even through debug).

It is something in NLog/`ILogger<>`, that it can't write log from another thread? And how to use it in this situation?

Comment: See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/3976

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the problem was hidden in fact, I was using DI with creating multiple scopes, so creating through this way doesn't work:

```
 var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
 serviceCollection.AddLogging(builder =>
 {
    builder.ClearProviders();
    builder.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
    builder.AddNLog($"{ConfigBasePath}/{NlogConfig}");
});
```

There are two solutions, create a single shared NLogFactory, and not for every DI container creation, with using static LogManager for setting config file. Or create multiple isolated LogFactory, through this code:

```
var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
serviceCollection.AddLogging(builder =>
{
   builder.ClearProviders();
   builder.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
   builder.AddNLog(serviceProvider => {
       var logFactory = new NLog.LogFactory();
       logFactory.LoadConfiguration($"{ConfigBasePath}/{NlogConfig}");
       return logFactory;
   });
});
```

My issue on [NLog GitHub](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/3976).

Comment: The first code example works great when only using a single dependency injection container together with the global static NLog.LogManager. But because you are creating multiple dependency-injection-containers, then it is only working when creating an isolated NLog LogFactory for each dependency-injection-container.